# How to solve this error - 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric''

Tags: pandas, module, pickle, modulenotfounderror

This is code for book recommender. I am getting this error in my Mac but this works perfectly in Windows.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle
import numpy as np
import os
import pickletools


popular_df = pickle.load(open('//Volumes//Work//1brs//book-recommender-system/popular.pkl', 'rb'))
pt = pickle.load(open('pt.pkl', 'rb'))
books = pickle.load(open('books.pkl', 'rb'))
similarity_scores = pickle.load(open('similarity_scores.pkl', 'rb'))

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',
                           book_name=list(popular_df['Book-Title'].values),
                           author=list(popular_df['Book-Author'].values),
                           image=list(popular_df['Image-URL-M'].values),
                           votes=list(popular_df['num_ratings'].values),
                           rating=list(popular_df['avg_rating'].values)
                           )


@app.route('/recommend')
def recommend_ui():
    return render_template('recommend.html')


@app.route('/recommend_books', methods=['post'])
def recommend():
    user_input = request.form.get('user_input')
    index = np.where(pt.index == user_input)[0][0]
    similar_items = sorted(list(enumerate(similarity_scores[index])), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[1:5]

    data = []
    for i in similar_items:
        item = []
        temp_df = books[books['Book-Title'] == pt.index[i[0]]]
        item.extend(list(temp_df.drop_duplicates('Book-Title')['Book-Title'].values))
        item.extend(list(temp_df.drop_duplicates('Book-Title')['Book-Author'].values))
        item.extend(list(temp_df.drop_duplicates('Book-Title')['Image-URL-M'].values))

        data.append(item)

    print(data)

    return render_template('recommend.html', data=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```

this is the code and this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Work/1brs/book-recommender-system/app.py", line 8, in <module>
    popular_df = pickle.load(open('//Volumes//Work//1brs//book-recommender-system/popular.pkl', 'rb'))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i have tried using virtual env and conda even global but still the same.
chatgpt keeps saying check pandas lib but still the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

looks like it was actually an error with pandas version

```
pip install "pandas<2.0.0"
```

by installing older pandas version it was solved

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting this error in my mac but this works perfectly in windows.

You understood that the problem is not your OS but your version of Pandas and you have downgraded it. Well but this is not a good long term solution.

`Pickle` module serialize the instance class of each object which is a problem when you upgrade `Python` or `Pandas`, etc. As you use `Flask`, it's a good idea to use a database with an ORM like `SQLAlchemy`. If you want to keep your code lite, choose a file format like `JSON` (or `Parquet`) to store your data.